# How to replace the clothes of person using GAN?

Tags: deep-learning, gan, image

I have one source video, let us say if the person is standing or walking in the video, the person's clothes should swap with the destination image (contain the picture of any clothes). I would like to use a GAN, like StyleGan for it. I am trying to find out the repository on Google if somebody has implemented it but I am not finding it. If you have an idea kindly share the link with me.

Comment: this is part of deepfake video generation and GAN are indeed an option, however the complexity of such approaches cannot be expressed fully in an answer, except possibly pointers for further study

Comment: see here for a start: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-produce-a-deepfake-video-in-5-minutes-513984fd24b6

Comment: Well , If you can share any github repository with me , it will more beneficial for me

Comment: Cross-posted: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/97473/8560, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/142031/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- VITON: An Image-based Virtual Try-on Network - https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.08447v4
- https://github.com/xthan/VITON